# How can I find a list of users having View All Data or View All opportunities permission?

Tags: permissions, salesforce, apex, soql

I am trying to run below query in Salesforce Developer Console to find out how many `permissionSetIDs` exist with **View All Data Permissions** or **View All Opportunities**. What's wrong with the below query?

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, PermissionsViewAllData, IsOwnedByProfile 
FROM PermissionSet
WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId 
             FROM ObjectPerms 
             WHERE SobjectType='Opportunity' 
               AND PermissionsViewAllRecords=true)
```

I see below error:

> > WHERE Id INn (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPerms WHEREe SobjectType='Opportunity'
>
> ERROR at Row:1:Column:112
> sObject type 'ObjectPerms' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change object name to correct type from `ObjectPerms` to `ObjectPermissions`

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, PermissionsViewAllData, IsOwnedByProfile
FROM PermissionSet
WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId
             FROM ObjectPermissions
             WHERE SobjectType='Opportunity'
               AND PermissionsViewAllRecords=true)
```